# Elixir Ecto - Association with 3 or more tables

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

if I have `profile`, `item`, `location` table which:

- `profile` has many `location`.
- `item` has one `location`.
- `location` in `profile` and `item` will NOT overlap.

How should I design the `location` table?
Is below valid?  `location` belongs to 2 tables?

```
schema "profiles" do
...
has_many :location, Location
end

schema "items" do
...
has_one :location, Location
end

schema "locations" do
...
belongs_to :profile, Profile
belongs_to :item, Item
end
```

or should there be 2 `location` tables?

Comment: I find it much easier to think about _tables_ first and foremost.  Abstractions in code (like Ecto or an ORM) are only useful inasmuch as they make your job of interacting with the data easier.  

I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "`location` in `profile` and `item` will NOT overlap", but I haven't followed the relationship between profiles and items.  You don't get extra points for defining all the relationships in your schema: I recommend starting with the queries you need, e.g. "A list of all items at a location", and establish the needed relationships to fulfill them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very subjective question and depends on how you are going to use the data from the `locations` table. This is generally the recommended approach for [polymorphic associations in Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/polymorphic-associations-with-many-to-many.html#polymorphic-todo-items) with an additional database constraint that forces that one of `profile_id` or `item_id` is always set on a location record.

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateLocations do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:locations) do
      add :profile_id, references(:profiles, on_delete: :delete_all)
      add :item_id, references(:items, on_delete: :delete_all)
    end

    create constraint(:locations, :at_least_one_ref, check: "profile_id is not null or item_id is not null")
    create index(:locations, [:profile_id, :item_id])
  end
end
```

And then in the changeset, you can validate this constraint:

```
def changeset(location, attrs) do 
  location
  |> cast(attrs, [:profile_id, :item_id])
  |> check_constraint(:profile_id, name: :at_least_one_ref)
end
```

Another way which is pretty specific to Ecto, but works really well, especially since you mentioned that there are no location overlap between profile and item is using embedded associations using [embeds_one](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_one/3) and [embeds_many](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/4). If you are using Postgres, you should even be able to create indexes on the JSONB column if you need to.

Comment: Actually that is what I am doing right now. Thanks for the answer anyway.